# How to search a string for the most common character or word in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a [question](https://github.com/Asabeneh/30-Days-Of-JavaScript/blob/master/02_Day_Data_types/02_day_data_types.md#exercises-level-3) that asked me to:

*Clean the following text and find the most frequent word: "`const sentence = '%I $am@% a %tea@cher%, &and& I lo%#ve %te@a@ching%;. The@re $is no@th@ing; &as& mo@re rewarding as educa@ting &and& @emp%o@weri@ng peo@ple. ;I found tea@ching m%o@re interesting tha@n any ot#her %jo@bs. %Do@es thi%s mo@tiv#ate yo@u to be a tea@cher!? %Th#is 30#Days&OfJavaScript &is al@so $the $resu@lt of &love& of tea&ching'`"*

I used regEx to clean the string like this:

```
const sentence = '%I $am@% a %tea@cher%, &and& I lo%#ve %te@a@ching%;. The@re $is no@th@ing; && mo@re rewarding than educa@ting &and& @emp%o@weri@ng peo@ple. ;I find tea@ching m%o@re interesting tha@n any ot#her %jo@bs. %Do@es thi%s mo@tiv#ate yo@u to be a tea@cher!? %Th#is 30#Days&OfJavaScript &is al@so $the $resu@lt of &love& of tea&ching';
const sentReg = /\W(?<!1)/g;
let sent = sentence.replace(/ /g, "1");

let finalSent = sent.replace(sentReg, ""), finalfinalSent = finalSent.replace(/1/g, " ");
```

I realized I don't know how to (or there might not be a way to) use the `match()` function to search a string by word, so I tried splitting it up into an array like:

```
let senArr = finalfinalSent.split(" "), wordOccur = [];

for (const x of senArr) {
    var re = new RegExp(x, "g");
    var y = finalfinalSent.match(re);

    wordOccur = wordOccur.concat([y.length]);
};
```

... and now I'm stuck because I don't know how to search an array in JavaScript, only in Python, and I feel the way to search through a string would be much easier than this. I would appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't change the spaces to "1". Instead use a regex that will not remove spaces while cleaning.

Then you can call `match` on the cleaned string, and use `reduce` to start counting words and maintain a reference to the most frequent one:

```js
const sentence = '%I $am@% a %tea@cher%, &and& I lo%#ve %te@a@ching%;. The@re $is no@th@ing; && mo@re rewarding than educa@ting &and& @emp%o@weri@ng peo@ple. ;I find tea@ching m%o@re interesting tha@n any ot#her %jo@bs. %Do@es thi%s mo@tiv#ate yo@u to be a tea@cher!? %Th#is 30#Days&OfJavaScript &is al@so $the $resu@lt of &love& of tea&ching';

let word = sentence.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, "")
            .match(/\w+/g)
            .reduce((acc, word) => {
                acc[word] = (acc[word] || 0) + 1;
                if (!(acc[word] < acc[acc.$])) acc.$ = word;
                return acc;
            }, {}).$;
            
console.log(word);
```

Observe that `acc` will be a "dictionary" of words, where the corresponding values are the counts. A special `$` entry is created in that same dictionary, which will hold the most frequent word.

If there is more than one word that has the maximum frequency, and you want to get *all* of these words, not just one, then return an array instead of a string:

```js
const sentence = '%I $am@% a %tea@cher%, &and& I lo%#ve %te@a@ching%;. The@re $is no@th@ing; && mo@re rewarding than educa@ting &and& @emp%o@weri@ng peo@ple. ;I find tea@ching m%o@re interesting tha@n any ot#her %jo@bs. %Do@es thi%s mo@tiv#ate yo@u to be a tea@cher!? %Th#is 30#Days&OfJavaScript &is al@so $the $resu@lt of &love& of tea&ching';

let word = sentence.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, "")
            .match(/\w+/g)
            .reduce((acc, word) => {
                acc[word] = (acc[word] || 0) + 1;
                if (!(acc[word] <= acc[acc.$])) acc.$ = [word];
                else if (acc[word] === acc[acc.$]) acc.$.push(word);
                return acc;
            }, {}).$;
            
console.log(word);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it became clearer. <3

Comment: But there are two of the most frequent words in a sentence: `love` and `teaching`.

Comment: What do you want to happen when there is a tie? In fact, "love" occurs one time less than "teaching", but "I" occurs just as many times as "teaching". I added a version for this.

Comment: My sincerest apologies. It was an accident that happened yesterday when I revisited the question from my phone. And I appreciate the follow-up on the answer.